# "NameError: name 'key' is not definedUnable to display" error using bottle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, bottle

x.py file:

```
from bottle import request, template,route,run,post

@route('/')
def index():
    return template('val.html')

@post('/result')
def result():
    result=request.forms
    print(result)       #Unable to print 

    return template("result",result = result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost',port=8080,debug='True',reloader='True')
```

val.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/result" method = "POST">
Select a time:
<input type="time" name="usr_time">
<br> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A is on" >A </input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B is on" >B </input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C" value="C is on" >C </input>
<br><br>
<input type="submit"> </input>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

result.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <table border = 1>
         {% for key, value in result.items() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

html files are placed inside views folder.

1) I'm trying to display the buttons clicked by user, but i'm getting the error -  "NameError: name 'key' is not definedUnable to display".

2) Also, i'm unable to print result. This works fine on flask if i use, `result= request.form` and then `print(result)`. This prints a dictionary on flask. But doesn't work using bottle. When i used `type(result)` it says = `<class 'bottle.FormsDict'>`. please help.

Comment: Are you missing your ending `%` before the closing `}`?

Comment: sorry, i've edited it now. still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

According to https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.11/stpl.html, "The % character is only recognized if it is the first non-whitespace character in a line."
So it should be written as below, to stay in python mode:

```
% for key, value in result.items()
...
% end
```

Comment: It's actually this. Got it.
    result.items():
Please edit you answer so i can mark it correct